# How do I Create a Scrolling Background in an Android App?

Tags: java, android

I'm a new Android developer, but I've worked through a few 2D games in Java.

However, I haven't really found a great way to do menus, and I would like to have an animated background movement on my main menu for this app.

Is there a certain method, like a graphics updater (paint) and then just set the x to scroll across the screen?

Note: It would be one image in the background, and I would want it to scroll (it's a simple pattern) to give the game menu some effects.  I'm assuming GIF images are out of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few options:

1. You use some image or other view and set the dimensions as needed, typically larger than of the screen. You then use this image inside a relative layout and set the left/top offsets to control the exact location.
2. You create a custom view that will draw appropriate image or whatever on the screen using the offsets.

I geneally prefer the second option since I do not have to restrict my view inside a relative layout.

Just to add - menus rendering is not under your control. It's controller by device theme and related (read: manufacturer).

Comment: A custom image was definitely what I was looking for, but I ended up throwing a big bimap in my AndroidFastRenderView for my game app.  Either way a scrolling background one pixel at a time seems resource tasking!  Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [**ScrollView**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) Class of Android, just define ScrollView in your .xml file as follows,

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    // Define your other components here.

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Oh I guess I wasn't clear enough.  I need a simple image to scroll, and it happens to be the background image.  Basically to add effect at the title screen of my game.

Comment: Scroll view will scroll the entire UI, and will also add a scrollbar. Not sure if that's desirable in this app unlike - for example, in a game like AngryBirds :-)

Comment: @MasterGaurav, yes agree with you. But i understood the question like that, that's why i have given this solution.

Comment: Yes, basically in a game like Angry Birds :)